# Cannot access callable attribute 'set_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains population of countries by year. I want to make the `country` column the index of the dataframe. I tried this:

```
df = df.set_index('Country')
```

Gives me an error:

> Cannot access callable attribute 'set_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy'
>   objects, try using the 'apply' method.

My data frame looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIu9t.png]

Comment: Give the code that provides you `df`. To get this error, you must have used `groupby` somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
df.set_index('Country', inplace=True)
```